# connect local MySql DB with nodejs on raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a server on a raspberry pi with a local DB I used [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-mysql/comment-page-1/?unapproved=88283&moderation-hash=25737290e2aa3ed1579079adb5d64088#comment-88283) guide to setup my database.

this is my connector in nodejs:

```
knexDb = knex({ client: ‘mysql’, 
                connection: { host: “localhost”, 
                              user: “myUsername”, 
                              password: “MyPassword”, 
                              port: 3306,
                              database: “DBName” } 
});
```

But when I try to access it with postman I get this error:

```
{ 
 “errno”: -111,
 “code”: “ECONNREFUSED”,
 “syscall”: “connect”,
 “address”: “::1”,
 “port”: 3306,
 “fatal”: true 
}
```

The nodejs is running, and I can access the DB on the raspberry pi, I have been searching on google but I haven't been able to find a solution only that the nodejs can't connect to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the host from `'localhost'` to `'127.0.0.1'` worked